# Fastest way to loop many times through dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe (500k rows, 250 columns). Each row is a football match.
Example of a part of df:

```
                 HOME_TEAM     AWAY_TEAM  GOL_HOME_FT  GOL_AWAY_FT ...
1153     Manchester United  Swansea City            1            2 
1163        Leicester City       Everton            2            2 
1172   Queens Park Rangers     Hull City            0            1
1183            Stoke City   Aston Villa            0            1
1193  West Bromwich Albion    Sunderland            2            2
```

Now, for EACH DIFFERENT TEAM in my dataframe, i want True or False if GOL_HOME_FT > GOL_AWAY_FT. Then i want to count max consecutive True.

Example of my code:

```
for team in list_teams:  # list_teams is all the different teams in my df
    df_team = df.loc[(df.HOME_TEAM.values == team) | (df.AWAY_TEAM.values == team)]
    lst_bool = df_team.GOL_HOME_FT.values > df_team.GOL_AWAY_FT.values
    consecutive_true = 0
    lst_consecutive_true = []
    for i in lst_bool:
        if i is True:
            consecutive_true  += 1
        else:
            lst_consecutive_true.append(consecutive_true)
            consecutive_true = 0
    max_consecutive_true = max(lst_consecutive_true)
```

But this is very slow! I have 5k different teams in my dataframe so i have to loop 5k time in my dataframe. I believe the slowest part is when i filter the dataframe.
Is there any fastest solution?

Comment: You almost never want to loop through a dataframe, there will be specific functions that are vectorized to help you do this faster.

Comment: Fastest way to loop pandas: `don’t`

Comment: something to read ... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this instead of loop.
Here is the data I used

```
HOME_TEAM                 AWAY_TEAM GOL_HOME_FT GOL_AWAY_FT lst_bool
ManchesterUnited          SwanseaCity   1          2    False
ManchesterCity            Everton       5          2    True
ManchesterParkRangers     HullCity      0          1    False
ManchesterCity            AstonVilla    0          1    False
ManchesterBromwichAlbion  Sunderland    2          2    False
ManchesterUnited          SwanseaCity   3          2    True
ManchesterUnited          SwanseaCity   3          2    True
ManchesterParkRangers     HullCity      2          1    True
```

I got the last column using this `df['lst_bool'] = df['GOL_HOME_FT']> df['GOL_AWAY_FT']`

Then to find consecutive true and false you can do this.
`(df.groupby(df.lst_bool.ne(df.lst_bool.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'lst_bool': 'count'})).reset_index(drop=True)`

This gave me the output below.

```
    lst_bool
0   1
1   1
2   3
3   3
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is to create a dataframe for each team using for loop. I'm trying groupby and then count True but I can't

Comment: If you want separate data frames separated by `HOME_TEAM` group then you could try this `grouped = df.groupby('HOME_TEAM')`    
`[grouped.get_group(x) for x in grouped.groups]`

Comment: Yes, thanks! But how do I do if i want groups by same team in HOME_TEAM and AWAY_TEAM? In other words, for example, I would like a group where Manchester is the HOME_TEAM or the AWAY_TEAM